# Stopping duplicate content with PHP within a Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Just when I thought I'd finished with all this php mallarky I spot another bug...

Basically I post a url, it spits it out. Sometimes I post the same url and I don't want the duplicates to show up.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
query_posts('');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$content = parse_url(strip_tags(get_the_content()));
$url = $content['host'];
?>

<li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $url; ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

I've tried modifying the loop to not fetch duplicate post ID's but I can't get it to work, either does nothing different or prints nothing at all. I've tried loading the $url into an array and then using array_unique() but again, no success, just spits out "Array Array Array" or errors. I'm sure it's easier than I think, I just can't get the code quite right I suspect...

I'd love some help please, I've been at this for a while and I'm all out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Why not try taking a look at the WP_Query options that Wordpress has implemented over the past couple of releases, I have always found these to be a more useful approach with the inclusion of Arrays and such like.

You can check out the codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

While not a direct answer it may lead you to a definitive answer in your quest!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, well, someone kindly helped me :)

```
<?php
    $url_list = array();
    query_posts('');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $content = parse_url(strip_tags(get_the_content()));
    $url = $content['host'];
    if(!in_array($url, $url_list)) {
?>

<li><a href="http://<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $url; ?></a></li>

<?php
    $url_list[] = $url;
    }

endwhile;
```

Cheers,
Craig.